# ValueError: time data '2021-11-05 10:13:46+11:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a string timestamp:

```py
ts = "2021-11-05 10:13:46+11:00"
```

That I would like to convert to a datetime using:

```py
datetime.strptime(ts, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
```

But I am getting a `ValueError`:

ValueError: time data '2021-11-05 10:13:46+11:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

I think this is happening because the "+11:00" has a ":" in it?

Heres the code to reproduce the error

```py
from datetime import datetime

ts = "2021-11-05 10:13:46+11:00"

date_ts = datetime.strptime(ts, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")

print(date_ts)
```

Comment: Use a capital `%Y` for your year, lowercase `%y` matches a two digit year. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Thank you! I was reading some different documentation that said the opposite. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

[`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat)

```py
>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2021-11-05 10:13:46+11:00")
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 5, 10, 13, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work well but unfortunately we have daylight savings in Australia so the offset would change if the value ```ts``` changed.

Comment: @HBates for handling daylight saving times properly, you'll need a *time zone*, not just a UTC offset as you seem to have as input (`+11:00`). Neither strptime nor fromisoformat will help you here, have a look at Python's `zoneinfo` for time zone handing.